# Codeigniter Model Not Inserting Value

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, crud

This is my 2nd web app in CI.

I am trying to grab a single value from a form (upon submit) and insert it into a database.

I have a controller "urlsubmission":

```
<?php

class Urlsubmission extends CI_Controller{

    function index() {
          $this->load->model('domaincheckmodel');
          $this->domaincheckmodel->verifyduplicates();

    }
}
?>
```

a model (domaincheckmodel) - which searches the db for a any duplicates:

```
<?php

    class Domaincheckmodel extends CI_Model{

        function __construct(){
            // Call the Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
        }


        function verifyduplicates(){
            #PREPARE DATA
            $sql = "SELECT tld from ClientDomain WHERE tld = ?";
            $postedTLD = $_POST['urlInput'];    // Get unsanitized data
            $endquery = $this->db->query($sql,array($this->db->escape_str($postedTLD))); // Query db

            #CONDITION
            if($endquery->num_rows() > 0){
                $this->load->view('err/domainexists'); ##domain already used
                ## please login..
            } 

            else{ #number of rows must be 0, insert into db
                $newDomain = "INSERT INTO ClientDomain(tld) VALUES('".$this->db->escape_str($postedTLD)."')";
                $this->load->view('success/domainfree');
                ## please register
            }
        }    
    }

    ?>
```

and two silly views right now: domainexists and domainfree:

domainexists:

```
<h2>Domain Exists</h2>
```

domainfree:

```
<h2>Domain free</h2>
```

The problem is: when I run the script, there are no errors, but it is properly executing `else{}` block, but not inputting anything into the database.

I have setup config/autoload to autoload the db lib, like:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't running the SQL query. Do this.

```
$newDomain = "INSERT INTO ClientDomain(tld) VALUES('".$this->db->escape_str($postedTLD)."')";
$this->db->query($newDomain);
```

or you can use simple_query()

```
$newDomain = "INSERT INTO ClientDomain(tld) VALUES('".$this->db->escape_str($postedTLD)."')";
$this->db->simple_query($newDomain);
```

Comment: Great point out, I knew I was doing something wrong. Silly me. Thanks @Cryptic !

Answer (score 0):

You declare the INSERT statement but never execute it?